# How to filter by relation column Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sql-order-by, relationship

How to filter by relation column

###### *tried this*

```
        ->whereHas('customer',function ($query) use ($order){
            $query->orderBy('first_name', $order);
        })
```

###### *and this*

```
        ->with(['customer' => function ($query) use ($order) {
            $query->orderBy('first_name', $order);
        }])
```

**Both did not work**

Comment: I don't need sortBy from collection ))

Comment: Orderby take second parameter as asc or desc and you are passing variable, what's the value of that variable?

Comment: string $order = 'desc'; yes, there will be only ASC, DESC,default desc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`with()` are using eager loading, which turns this into two queries.

You need to use `join()` instead of `with()`

```
$orders = Order
        ::join('customers', 'order.customer_id', '=', 'customers.id')
        ->orderBy('customers.first_name')
        ->get();
```

**OR**

You may use [`sortBy()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-sortby) or [`sortByDesc()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-sortbydesc) methods of `Collection`.

For example:

```
$orders = Order
        ::with('customer')
        ->get()
        ->sortBy('customer.first_name');
```

Comment: yeah `with` and `whereHas` didn't work. i used `LeftJoin`.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

request `{{host}}/admin/showcases?filterBy=companies:name` it order by relation column companies

if simple `{{host}}/admin/showcases?filterBy=name`
it will be only `orderBy("name")`

```
->when(str_contains($filterBy, ':'),
                function (Builder $query) use ($filterBy, $order, $columns) {
                    $table = explode(':', $filterBy)[0];
                    $key = Str::singular($table) . "_id";
                    $column = explode(':', $filterBy)[1];
                    $selfTable = $this->getTable();
                    $query->leftJoin($table, "$selfTable.$key", "$table.id")
                            ->when($columns !== ['*'],
                                    function ($query) use ($columns, $selfTable) {
                                        $columns = array_map(function ($column) use ($selfTable) {
                                            return "$selfTable.$column";
                                        }, $columns);
                                        $query->select($columns);
                                    },
                                    fn($query) => $query->select(["$selfTable.*"]))
                            ->orderBy("$table.$column", $order);
                },
                function ($query) use ($filterBy, $order) {
                    $query->orderBy($filterBy, $order);
                })
```